# GCP issue , two VMs can not ping each other by using external ipv6

Tags: google-cloud-platform

VM1

IPv4 : 10.100.100.101 ( internal )

IPv6 : 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0 ( external )

VM2

IPv4 : 10.100.100.102 ( internal )

IPv6 : 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0 ( external )

For IPv4 :

- 10.100.100.101 and 10.100.100.102 can ping each other , works fine .

For IPv6 :

- From internet , can ping 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0 and 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0 , works fine .
- **But , 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0 and 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0 CAN NOT ping each other .**

And according to GCP Document :
**External IPv6 addresses can be used for VM to VM communication within VPC networks, and are also routable on the internet.** To control egress to and ingress from the internet, configure firewall rules or hierarchical firewall policies. To disable IPv6 routing to the internet completely, delete the IPv6 default route in the VPC network.

My problem is focused on **IPv6** :

**Internet hosts can ping to VM1 and VM2 , but why VM1 and VM2 can not ping each other ? It's weird .**

**Can anyone help ?**

Below is my setting and test :

VM1 ( tjtw8 )

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc fq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 42:01:0a:64:64:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.100.100.101/32 brd 10.100.100.101 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 3450sec preferred_lft 3450sec
inet6 2001:b000:4030:67d0::/128 scope global dynamic
   valid_lft 3431sec preferred_lft 3431sec
inet6 fe80::11e6:ba8f:81a2:8165/64 scope link noprefixroute
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

VM2 ( tjtw9 )

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 42:01:0a:64:64:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.100.100.102/32 brd 10.100.100.102 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
   valid_lft 2549sec preferred_lft 2549sec
inet6 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1::/128 scope global noprefixroute dynamic
   valid_lft 3599sec preferred_lft 3599sec
inet6 fe80::9fe5:71b4:5ee7:6283/64 scope link noprefixroute
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

VM1 ping VM2

```
 [root@tjtw8 ~]# ping -6 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0
 PING 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0(2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1::) 56 data bytes
 From 2001:b000:4030:67d0::: icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
 From 2001:b000:4030:67d0::: icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
 From 2001:b000:4030:67d0::: icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

VM2 ping VM1

```
 [root@tjtw9 ~]# ping -6 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0
 PING 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0(2001:b000:4030:67d0::) 56 data bytes
```

It's weird , it doesn't show **Destination unreachable** .

Internet Host ping VM1

```
 [root@nat ~]# ping -6 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0
 PING 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:0:0:0(2001:b000:4030:67d0::) 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 2001:b000:4030:67d0::: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=13.5 ms
 64 bytes from 2001:b000:4030:67d0::: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=10.8 ms
 64 bytes from 2001:b000:4030:67d0::: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=13.3 ms
```

Internet Host ping VM2

```
 [root@nat ~]# ping -6 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0
 PING 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:0:0(2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1::) 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1::: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=11.6 ms
 64 bytes from 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1::: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=13.6 ms
 64 bytes from 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1::: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=11.5 ms
```

I tried anything i can do , but still can not figure out .
Can anyone help ?

Comment: I cannot read Chinese. Because you posted images, I cannot use a translator. Your firewall rule `subnet-1-allow-ipv6-icmp` appears correct. My guess is you are using the `ping` command IPv6 addresses wrong. Edit your post and show the `ping` command and responses in your post. Include internal system to internal system from both sides. Include an example that works from the Internet to one of the internal systems. Do not use images, post only text. Include the output from `ip addr` from both systems, which will show the network configuration of each one.

Comment: I updated the imges too in english .

Comment: I am not sure how the route was broken. Try this command on VM1: `ip -6 route add default via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401`. Note: anytime you modify addresses and routes, you can break your system. Always have a backup, image, or snapshot unless this is a test system.

Comment: FYI: Here is the problem VM1: `2600:1900:4030:67d0::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium`. There is no route. Compare with `2600:1900:4030:67d0::/65 via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my test , i check the routing table , found that :

VM1 ( tjtw8 )

```
 2001:b000:4030:67d0:: dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 3524sec pref medium
 2001:b000:4030:67d0::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
 unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
 fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 pref medium
 fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
 default via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 pref medium
```

VM2 ( tjtw9 )

```
 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:1:: dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
 2001:b000:4030:67d0::/65 via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
 unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
 fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
 default via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

**These two VM's routing tables are little bit different ( i didn't modify routing table ) .**

GCP gives me ipv6 address range is : **/64** .

But why the routing table in **VM1 is /64** and in **VM2 is /65** ??

I think all VM's routing table should be **/64** ( not /65 ) .

OK , let me try this :

I create the 3rd VM ( named : tjtw10 ) .

VM3 ( tjtw10 )

```
 2001:b000:4030:67d0:0:2:: dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
 2001:b000:4030:67d0::/65 via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
 unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo metric 1024 error -113 pref medium
 fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
 default via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
```

See ?

VM2 and VM3 , their routing table are the same , and VM3 is also **/65** .

But the first created VM1 , it's routing table is different from VM2 and VM3 , kind of weird .

So , the final result is :

- VM1 and VM2 CAN NOT ping each other .
- VM1 and VM3 CAN NOT ping each other .
- VM2 and VM3 CAN ping each other .

Back to my question ( IPv6 problem ) :

**It's the routing table problem , even though i don't know why GCP made different routing table in my first created VM1 ( tjtw8 ) .**

Solution :

When you reboot the VM , GCP will auto generate their routing table into your VM .

To avoid this , you can modify the routing table by adding route command ( **ip -6 route add** or **ip -6 route del** ) into **/etc/rc.local** ( rc.local must be excutable) , so it will make the route correct permanently .

So i need to chagne VM1's route to match VM2 and VM3 , so i add 3 route command in VM1's /etc/rc.local :

```
 ip -6 route add 2001:b000:4030:67d0::/65 via fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0
 ip -6 route del 2001:b000:4030:67d0::/64 dev eth0
 ip -6 route del fe80::4001:aff:fe64:6401 dev eth0
```

So when VM1 reboot , VM1's route will be correct , this resolved my problem .

End.

Comment: /65 is GCP problem right ? It's very weird . Because my VPC Network -> Route is /64 ( this is GCP gives me by default )

Comment: Show the exact command you used.

Comment: I do not think `/65` is the problem or even a problem at all. You have a routing problem and not an addressing problem. Read my comments to your question. The route was missing for VM1. Why it is missing is an interesting question.